# Failed to resolve module on VSCode

Tags: rascal

my rascal project on VSCode fails to resolve imported module, am I doing something wrong but the code works;
[image]

{Edit}
Here are the pom.xml and RASCAL.MF file(respectively) in my project:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument> 
          <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.rascalmpl</groupId>
        <artifactId>rascal-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <errorsAsWarnings>true</errorsAsWarnings>
          <bin>${project.build.outputDirectory}</bin>
          <srcs>
            <src>${project.basedir}/src/main/rascal</src>
          </srcs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

```
Manifest-Version: 0.0.1
Project-Name: rsctest
Source: src/main/rascal
Require-Libraries:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess, but I'm sharing it in case it can be of any benefit.

- On a file system with case-insensitive path names, the Rascal interpreter may resolve a module named `compile::Entities` via a path name that is `compile/entities.rsc`, and therefore *accidentally* "work". This might explain why "it works".
- However, module names in Rascal are not case-insensitive by design, they are case-sensitive, and therefore the type-checker will *certainly* complain about the import not being resolved. This would explain the message `Undefined module ...`

If this is the problem then changing `import compile::entities;` to `import compile::Entities;` would fix the issue.

If this is not the problem, there is something else going on and I'd like to see the contents of the `META-INF/RASCAL.MF` file and the `pom.xml` file and a recursive directory listing of the source folder to help diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it didn't work I added the pom.xml and .mf file on the question